# Materialized view in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, materialized-views

I came across the following command in a documentation : bq mk --materialized_view

I would like to know whether the bq mk --materialized_view command in Bigquery creates a materialized view 
?

Thanks
Thirumalai

Comment: Please provide the link to the page.

Comment: It was from the recently released Google Bigquery book. Link : https://books.google.co.in/books?id=-Jq4DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181&dq=bq+mk+materialized+view&source=bl&ots=Qgv90_83VF&sig=ACfU3U16eodpDA-33neNQ31GpeB41i6FoQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmtZzIt7rmAhV3yjgGHRoKAsIQ6AEwA3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=bq%20mk%20materialized%20view&f=false

Comment: I pinged the author, hopefully he will see this post.

Comment: You need to contact the [GCP support](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/getting-support#get_a_google_support_package) team for this, as this feature requires to get a private access.

Comment: What is a private access ?

Comment: What is a private access ? Where can I get more details regarding this feature ? Because in the book there aren't much details.

Comment: You can track this feature request for updates on materialized view in BigQuery: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62244996

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Materialized views are an alpha project - access is limited to a few accounts while the feature continues its development.

Please follow this issue for updates:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62244996

Comment: Thanks Felipe. We are planning to denormalize our existing fact table which right now connects to more than 10+ dimension tables, so we are thinking that we can make use of Materialized views for this purpose. Is it a good idea to use MV instead of denormalized tables ? How the MV's in Bigquery would be refreshed ? Will it always be full refresh or does it support incremental refresh ? Say for example if only 1 row in the underlying dimension table gets changed then whether the whole MV will be refreshed or this single row alone would be updated in the MV ?

Answer (score 1):

It is beta now:

> BigQuery Materialized View are precomputed views that periodically cache results of a query for increased performance and efficiency. BigQuery leverages precomputed results from materialized views and whenever possible reads only delta changes from the base table to compute up-to-date results. Materialized views can be queried directly or can be used by the BigQuery optimizer to process queries to the base tables.
>
> Queries that use materialized views are generally faster and consume less resources than queries that retrieve the same data only from the base table. Materialized views are helpful to significantly boost performance of workloads that have the characteristic of common and repeated queries.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro

Answer (score 1):

Materialized views is now GA.

Basic docs: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro

BQ CLI reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#mk-materializedview